# problems on congruent number generating and others...

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

From where we got this congruent generating function $n = pq(p+q)(p-q)$?

how to prove 1- is non-congruent number?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is "congruent generating function"?

Comment: This is came form $A^2 + B^2 = C^2$. I think...

Comment: Here A = 2pq, B = $p^2 - q^2$ and C = B = $p^2 + q^2$. Then how we get n and what is the relation of generating function n and stuff...

Comment: If Old John's answer told you what you want to know, you should "accept" it by clicking in the check mark next to it. If Old John's answer wasn't what you wanted, you should edit your question to make it clearer what exactly you want.

Answer (score 2):

From the standard formula for the sides of a Pythagorean triple ($A, B, C$) we have $A = 2pq, B = p^2-q^2, C=p^2+q^2$, as you noted in your comment. The area of the corresponding right-angled triangle (which has the right-angle between $A$ and $B$), the area is

$$\Delta = \displaystyle\frac12 AB = \displaystyle\frac12 .2pq.(p^2-q^2) = pq(p-q)(p+q)$$

This formula gives congruent numbers by taking the largest squarefree part of $\Delta$. For example, taking $p=5, q=4$ gives $\Delta = 180$ of which the squarefree part is $5$, showing that $5$ is a congruent number.

Note that all congruent numbers will be found this way, but they do not crop up in any regular way, so this is not an efficient way to find congruent numbers.

For the last part of your question, the proof that $1$ is not a congruent number is equivalent to the statement that there is no Pythagorean triple whose area is a square number. One proof uses infinite descent, and an very clear exposition can be found in the excellent notes by Keith Conrad [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/congnumber.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

It is Piere de Fermat (1601-1665) who proved that $n=1$ is NOT a congruent number, and also that $n=2$ is  NOT congruent.

A discussion of his proof may be found in J.D. Sally and P.J. Sally Jr. Roots to Research. American Mathematical Society, Ch 2, p97, 2007.

A congruent number $n$ is defined as the integer area of a rational right triangle. When $n$ is square-free, $n$ is called a "reduced congruent number".

All unreduced congruent numbers can be characterized as the product of four integers of the generalized Fibonacci sequence $(q',q,p,p')$, where $q'$ is odd and where the members of the sequence are pair-wise coprime. This product, $p=(q'\cdot q\cdot p\cdot p')$,  is a congruent number and is the area A of a primitive triple with sides $a=q'p',\qquad b=2qp, \qquad c= pp'-qq'$.

Dividing out any square factor from this product $p=(q'\cdot q\cdot p\cdot p')$ yields another congruent number. When no square factors remain we have a "reduced congruent number".  For example, $p=(1\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 9)$ is congruent, and so are $(4\cdot 5)$ and $(5\cdot 9)$. The only non-square factor is 5, a "reduced congruent number".